# J2ME file upload to Rails server fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, java-me, upload, multipart

My J2ME application uploads image files to a Rails server using multipart upload.

But it works fine with PHP server.  The Rails server response is "The change you wanted was rejected (422)". I use both Rails 2.3.8 and 2.3.3.

Here is the code I use: http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_with_J2ME

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by Rails' CSRF protection.

You need to include in your parameters the correct authenticity token from Rails. You can get this by using a GET request before the POST. (Only POST requests are checked for authenticity)

Another way to bypass this is to just disable CSRF protection. Delete the line `protect_from_forgery` in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

Learn more here: [Ruby on Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html)